# SDL Web8 with DXA 1.6: Unable to use multiple publications in CMS that will server the pages and content for a single web application hosted on IIS

Tags: web8, dxa, mvc

I am using SDL Web 8 with DXA1.6 framework to create MVC Webapplication. As per DXA reference implementation guide it ask to create mapping using Toplogy Manager cmdlet. This step forces to have 1 to 1 mapping between publication and webapplication(deployed in IIS)

```
Add-TtmMapping -Id {MAPPINGID} -PublicationId {PUBID} -WebapplicationId {WEBAPPLICATION}_RootWebApp
```

But my webapplication needs to serve webpages for multiple US states + languages combination. Thus I have below six publications from where i will be publishing the content and pages to be used in my web application and in future it may add up more to the list.

Publications in CMS:

publication 1 : website {US State1}_ENGLISH

publication 2 : website {US State1}_SPANISH

publication 3 : website {US State2}_ENGLISH

publication 4 : website {US State2}_SPANISH

publication 5 : website {US State3}_ENGLISH

publication 6 : website {US State3}_SPANISH

website URLs list:

http://{domain-name}/{state1}/{language1}/{page-name}

http://{domain-name}/{state1}/{language2}/{page-name}

http://{domain-name}/{state2}/{language1}/{page-name}

http://{domain-name}/{state2}/{language2}/{page-name}

http://{domain-name}/{state3}/{language1}/{page-name}

http://{domain-name}/{state3}/{language2}/{page-name}

Comment: Have you seen http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v6/GUID-7D334E4E-72F7-4AAA-B541-7A845E15C88C and http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v6/GUID-FAA818E4-2851-4A14-9492-70361D9BC801 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your requirements, I see the following Topology Manager configuration:

- 1 Website with Base URL `http://{domain-name}`
- 1 Web Application with Context URL `/` (Root Web App)
- 6 Mappings with Relative URLs `{stateX}/{languageY}` and associated Publication.

Comment: thanks Rick this approach works perfectly fine and webpage able to render content now for state and language combinations in the url. For the common asset files (css, js). I am planning to publish that from Master Website publication so that for these asset files, there will common reference path used in pages (pages are created in publications meant for `<state><language>` combinations)

Comment: Hi Rick; I am facing one limitation after defining 6 mappings with Relative Urls {stateX}/{languageY}. It gives below error if any url is hit which falls outside of the defined 6 Mappings. for example say the url http://{domain}/redirect/?url=http://www.google.com or any other url which does not contain <state><language> after domain name. Error: "No Matching Localization found for the URL 'http://{domain}/redirect/'"